# How to prevent fullscreen on Android browser?

Tags: android, cross-browser, html5-video

We have a simple HTML5 video tag and video which, when played, should play the video within the current div it rests in. On some android devices the default action for play() seems to be to jump to fullscreen.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: There are many browsers for Android. There is unlikely to be a universal answer for all of them.

Comment: I was hoping there might be a way of communicating with the OS or the media player through JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as far as I know. There is no way to specify that a video should or should not play full-screen using HTML5. Playing the video full-screen instead of in-place is a decision made by the browser because it makes sense for most sites...